# Xtext - enum literal overrides id

Tags: parsing, enums, grammar, xtext

I have following excerpt of my grammar, where the rule `Format` seems to override the `FieldColumnName` rule.

```
Statement:
    'select * from' table=Table where=WhereClause;

WhereClause: 
    'where' symbol=FieldColumn op="=" right=STRING; 

FieldColumn:
    fieldName=FieldColumnName;

FieldColumnName hidden():
    ID ('.' ID)?;

enum Format:
    iso | de | en;
```

Developing an DSL-Script on following grammar I am getting an validation error in the editor, with following `Statement`:

```
select * from foo where foo.de = 'bar';
```

The error marks the `de` in `foo.de` and its message is:

> mismatched input 'de' expecting RULE_ID

How can I use reserved words like the `de` in contexts where I do not expect that keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be very careful with spaces in keywords. Please try to refactor your grammar, e.g. use `'select' '*' 'from'` instead of `'select * from'`. 
To fix your issue, you'll have to introduce a rule `ValidID: ID | 'de' |'en' | 'iso';` and use ValidID instead of ID in FieldColumnName.

Comment: The mentioned grammar is just an example to show my problem. In my "real" grammar, the select statement is set up a little more complex. And the work with Xtext learned me exactly what you advise me. 
I have changed my grammar according to your answer and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, one problem left: In the editor the keywords used in an ID still marked as keyword. How can I prevent the editor of highlighting the valid IDs, containing a keyword literal?

Comment: You will need to implement a semantic highlighter to adjust the coloring.